# Will there be another Common Lisp standard?

Tags: common-lisp

I realize this is a broad question, but given "what we know now" vs. "what we knew then" and Greenspun's Tenth Rule, are there efforts to "modernize" (evolve) Common Lisp or has this been considered? Are there working groups that consider this question? Is there still interest in an (incrementally improved) ANSI Standard for Common Lisp?

Comment: This is probably not the best place to ask. Did you try some forum/list/group dedicated to Common Lisp?

Comment: Here is where the experts are... but happy to look elsewhere. CL doesn't need to be redefined, as other efforts have attempted with various degrees of failure. It could be incrementally improved.

Comment: " It could be incrementally improved."  I that happens, actually.  As more implementation support some of the common interfaces (e.g., quicklisp, various threading APIs, etc.), some fairly standard things come about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This question has been asked on `comp.lang.lisp` many times and the answer is **NO**.

Changing a standard is extremely expensive in terms of time of experts. Lisp vendors have neither resources nor incentives to do that.

Nor there is any need for that: the language as specified is good enough, what it lacks is standard interfaces to various libraries. This issue is addressed by individual vendors.

Comment: I was avoiding researching the morass of Usenet flame wars, having been through a few, myself. That said, things that don't evolve often die off. Which would be a shame in the case of CL.

Comment: @ScottM: CL does evolve, just not via the ANSI process.

Answer (score 1):

It isn't a standard, but you may be interested in [CL21](http://cl21.org/).